how to set the input i/o in the output rung in the plc ladder diagram
I am using the Delta AS228T-A plc model and DIA Designer software to program the plc, i want to set the input gpio(X0.0) in the output rung like this below image

It throws me an error before i upload "test error, the output coil must be set from M,Y..."

X's are typically INPUTs, so they are usually flagged as READ ONLY.  This is the reason for the error.
The I/O module updates the X status before every logic scan.  So, "technically" its NOT READONLY, but from a logic standpoint, it is.
So if it's tied to a Limit Switch, you are attempting to OVERRIDE the status of the Limit Switch from the physical input switch status to the state of M105.
If you truly want to be able to LOGICALLY override X's, I would map ALL the X's to a different block of BITs at the Top of Scan.  Then use those "internal" bits in lieu of the actual X bits.  Now you can easily "override" the state of this "X" like you are trying to do (replace X0.0 with the specific internal bit memory element that is associated with X0.0).  But you MUST MAP all your Physical Discrete Inputs (X) to an Internal block of bits via logic somehow.

sorry for the delay. Thanks for your suggestion. I would try that.
